# express middleware mongodb execution not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Using express middleware fetching user information from mongodb on page request.

Try to set userInfo in request but I am not getting userinfo in request please check the below code and suggest me.

app.js

```
app.use(userManager.userManager);
```

userManager.js

```
"use strict";

var USERModel = require("./user_schema");

module.exports.userManager = function(req, res, next) {

        var assoString = "US";
        var options = {
            limit: 1
        };
        USERModel.textSearch(assoString, options, function (err, output) {

             if (err) {
              console.error("USERModel.textSearch:" ,err);
             }
             else if (output && output.results && output.results.length > 0) {

                 req.userInfo = output.results[0].obj.userDetail;

             }
             else {
                 console.warn("Empty USERModel for ", assoString);

             }
     });
};
```

user_schema.js

```
"use strict";

var db = require('../lib/db_connect');
var textSearch = require("mongoose-text-search");

var userSchema = new db.Schema({
    associatedwith  : String,
    userDetail: {
                userId      : {type: String},
                cId        : {type: String},  
                device          : {type: String},
                contentType     : {type: String},
                isCompression   : {type: Boolean},
                renderType      : {type: String}

            }

    }
);

userSchema.plugin(textSearch);


var USERModel  = module.exports = db.mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need or reply the http request (with `res.send`, `res.json`, `res.end` and family) or invoke the callback to pass the request to the next middleware or route handler:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    // Rest of the logic
    res.send(200,'Everything went OK'); // The request is replied here
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    // Rest of the logic
    next(); // To the next middleware/route logic
});
```